# Remove all UIViewControllers from app and start fresh

Tags: ios, uikit

When my user logs out I want to remove all UIViewController's and UIView's from the window and start again with a new view controller.

My problem is that when I set the window's rootViewController to a new view controller and I debug the app's view hierarchy, I can see the new view, however the old views are simply behind the new one. They do not get removed and are still in memory.

How can I remove all view controllers and views first?

Answer (score 0):

Remove old hierarchy from key window before setting the new one.

```
let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view?.removeFromSuperview()
keyWindow?.rootViewController == //...
```

Comment: I've just tried removing all the window's subviews but the view controllers still aren't dealloc'd: `window.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }`. I should note I've also got a modally presented view controller as well, which may complicate things.

Comment: without additional info I can't really help you. I can recommend you to setup tab view controller as root controller of you application (with hidden tab bar) and then replace that single item with the new controller. this way you will avoid changing root controller and tab controller will handle entire management for you.

Comment: This simply does not work. The previous view still remains underneath.